# Cron not call sh script

Tags: cron

Works:

```
crontab -e
  * * * * * date >> /home/pi/scripts/test.log
```

Doesn't Work:

```
crontab -e
  * * * * * /home/pi/scripts/test.sh
```

test.sh

```
  #!/bin/hash 
  * * * * * date >> /home/pi/scripts/test.log
```

please tell me where problem this is my first tested raspberry :-)

---

`/etc/init.d/cron status -l`

```
cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Po 2016-03-21 21:27:41 CET; 15min ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 12087 (cron)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─12087 /usr/sbin/cron -f

bře 21 21:40:01 rbpi CRON[13517]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
bře 21 21:41:01 rbpi CRON[13612]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
bře 21 21:41:02 rbpi CRON[13619]: (root) CMD (/home/pi/scripts/test.sh)
bře 21 21:41:02 rbpi CRON[13612]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
bře 21 21:42:01 rbpi CRON[13770]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
bře 21 21:42:01 rbpi CRON[13777]: (root) CMD (/home/pi/scripts/test.sh)
bře 21 21:42:01 rbpi CRON[13770]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
bře 21 21:43:01 rbpi CRON[13865]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
bře 21 21:43:01 rbpi CRON[13872]: (root) CMD (/home/pi/scripts/test.sh)
bře 21 21:43:01 rbpi CRON[13865]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: For starters, what's that with all the asterikses in the shell script?

Comment: @Ghanima: they're modeling it after the cron call...

Comment: what is the ownership and permission of test.sh? Does the test.sh script work if called from the commandline? did you make tets.sh executable? Aslo, what is it you are trying to do? As it stands you are attempting to write the date to a log file every second?

Answer (score 2):

The `*`s in your crontab specifies when to run the command. The `*`s mean to run the command at every minute, of every hour, of every day of the month, of every month, of every day of the week.

In your shell script "*" isn't something you want to specify at the beginning of the line. The asterisk means, basically, all files in the current directory, which isn't what you're trying to run for your command; you want to run `date`.

Remove the asterisks from your shell script.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot wrong with your **b**ash script.

For starters the shebang is wrong. It should be `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/hash`.

Your other issue is including all the asterisks (`*`) in your bash script. They're used in the cron entry to tell it when it should be run, but cause errors in the actual shell script. Change the second line of `test.sh` to just `date >> /home/pi/scripts/test.log`.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the asterisks in the .sh script, as they're only valid in a crontab.

```
#!/bin/bash 
date >> /home/pi/scripts/test.log
```

Otherwise, bash expands every single * into a list of all the files in the working directory, which isn't a valid command!

Comment: Yes sorry test.sh   date >> /home/pi/scripts/test.log